# Log4j and User expectation

Tags: log4j

Log4j doesn't seem the best way to notify the end user. My experience is that users don't care much if an entry is INFO, WARN, ERROR, etc. They care only about if they need to do something about the "error"?

Like Log4j, which seems more targeted at developers, are there log levels more targeted at the end-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best" way, but you are correct on Log4J being a more developer-centered tool. However, you could also have more than 1 appenders. One for developers and one for customers.

On the developer, you'd use the log levels that we know and love: WARN, INFO, ERROR... and for the customer appender you would have only INFO, but the message itself would specify if the customer needs to do something or not.